# Issues centering button in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Can someone help me center the Outline button horizontally? Crossalignmentaxis.center doesnt seem to work.

```
Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      OutlineButton(
                        child: Text(
                          'Hours',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 45.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: 'HousePlant2'),
                        ),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                            width: 2),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` for the `Row`, because the main axis for a row is the horizontal axis and the cross axis for a row is the vertical axis.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Container(
         // color: Colors.red,
            child: Center(
              child: Row(mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  OutlineButton(
                    child: Text(
                      'Hours',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 45.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'HousePlant2'),
                    ),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                        width: 2),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```